# Assigning a value to a pointer that does not point to anything in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a bit of code that looks something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
 void doSomething(std::string& stringvar) {
   // Does something
}}
class AnotherClass
{ /* Some data structure */ }
```

And then in the main, the programmer calls

```
MyClass* Class1;
std::string myString = "something";
AnotherClass* SecondClass; 
SecondClass = (*Class1).doSomething(myString);
```

My question is, what does this do, since I am defining a pointer that points to nothing and then setting its value? To what does it set a value to? A random memory slot? And where? In stack or heap? And why would someone create a class only to write a function that does something? I don't really understand the class MyClass, is it possible that doSomething actually fills some data structure? If yes, then how and where if it is also a pointer that points to nothing?

Comment: It's undefined behavior so what it does is undefined.

Comment: Creating a pointer `MyClass *Class1` points to garbage on the stack. So it would crash.

Comment: @M4rc that is in no way guaranteed

Comment: Just don’t do it. What more would you need to know?!

Comment: Undefined. Also depends on your Compiler

Comment: I don't do it, someone before me did it, I am trying to understand this. And somehow it works :D

Comment: Do you mean `secondVar = (*Class1).doSomething(myString);`?

Comment: Maybe `doSomething` doesn't access the object, so the uninitialized `this` variable doesn't get referenced. If so, it should probably be rewritten as a static method.

Comment: Yeah, sure Martin, thanks, it was a typo :)

Comment: Biffen - sorry, forgot to define SecondClass as another non-pointing pointer by it. :D

Comment: Assigning the return value of a void function to a variable… How are you compiling this?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am defining a pointer that points to nothing and then setting its value? To what does it set a value to? A random memory slot? And where? In stack or heap?

Well, quite. There is no answer. The results are, literally, undefined. It [could](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49032606/560648) send an electromagnetic pulse into my right eyeball.

> And why would someone create a class only to write a function that does something?

Incompetence exists.

> I don't really understand the class MyClass, is it possible that doSomething actually fills some data structure?

It's possible, but we can't tell you without seeing it.

> If yes, then how and where if it is also a pointer that points to nothing?

Some people think that they can call a member function through a dodgy pointer, as long as they did not use any member variables, because "it worked for me".

Those people are wrong. The program has undefined behaviour.

I once worked with someone who habitually did this with static member functions, because they did not know that you could (should) write `Class1::doSomething(myString)` instead!

Comment: Thanks. The class calls some dodgy fortran routines, I can not really elaborate without showing you the whole framework, the information I give you would be always incomplete. I am not really a C++ programmer, I am a physicist, who uses a C++ framework to analyze some data. But I want to understand it. Also, I have a strong feeling that the framework was not written by a programmer, but also by a physicist.

Comment: @user74200: I suspect your feeling is accurate.

Answer (score 4):

As you have phrased the question, it is undefined behaviour.  That means anything is allowed to happen.  *One* of the things that could happen is that it works just as the programmer intended.  This is particularly likely if `doSomething` is a non-virtual function, and doesn't access any of the class's (non-static) member variables.

**This is still undefined behaviour**.  It could stop working as soon as you change something completely unrelated.

If my diagnosis is correct, the solution is to make `doSomething` a static member function, and invoke it as:

```
    secondVar = MyClass::doSomething(mystring);
```