# I have a question about printf() function

Tags: c++, c, pointers, operating-system

I want to know why the second print function can print a? and the third print function not print a?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 97; // a

    printf(&i); // a：print content in address &i  
    printf("\n%s\n", &i); // why print a?
    printf("%c\n", &i); // why not print a?
}
```

I want to understand printf function from pointer and memory. Thank you

Comment: None of these examples are valid. Are you trying to understand why that is? You should not attempt to understand the behavior in any other way because it is undefined. Perhaps it would be more practical for you to focus on learning how pointers and the type system work, rather than trying to understand what happens when you abuse them.

Comment: See [Why is the phrase: "undefined behavior means the compiler can do anything it wants" true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032551/why-is-the-phrase-undefined-behavior-means-the-compiler-can-do-anything-it-wan)

Comment: It is legitimate to ask questions about what is actually happening in a particular instance of UB.  Don't just dismiss people who want to understand what happened _this time_ (but be clear that it isn't guaranteed to happen _next time_).

Comment: Incidentally, a trivial modification of the second case makes it not UB (merely impl-def)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what is 'expected'.

If it's an address (%s), it will go to and read the contents of that address.

If it's a value (%c), it won't go anywhere and take it literally.

Answer (score 4):

These are fun mistakes to make:

```
printf(&i); // a：print content in address &i
```

The first argument to `printf()` should always be a pointer (e.g. a `const char *`) to a format-string, but you are passing in an `int *` instead.  Since `printf()` is a variadic function it has no good way of knowing that the pointer is pointing to the wrong type of data, so it will happily try to interpret the binary bytes of `i` (and possibly beyond it) as ASCII characters, resulting in some interesting but not-very-useful output, and potentially a crash.  If an `a` shows up in the output, it's because you are running on a machine with a little-endian CPU, so (assuming a 32-bit CPU) the bytes of the `int` with value `97` are laid out like this in memory:

```
0x61, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
```

... which you will notice just happens to be the same byte-pattern as a NUL-terminated ASCII string "a" (followed by two extra NUL bytes).  If you were running on a big-endian machine instead (e.g. a PowerPC Mac), then the bytes of the int would be laid out like this:

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x61
```

... and in that case nothing would be printed because `printf()` would hit the first `0x00` byte first and therefore (mis)interpret the data as an empty/0-character string.

```
printf("\n%s\n", &i); // why print a?
```

This is the same as the previous example, except that you've (correctly) provided a formatting-string before (incorrectly) passing a pointer-to-int in the second argument (where the `%s` means that `printf()` was expecting a pointer-to-chars argument instead)

```
printf("%c\n", &i); // why not print a?
```

In this case you're passing a pointer-value, but the `%c` in the format-string means that `printf()` was expecting an integer as the second argument.  Therefore `printf()` is interpreting the memory-address as an integer, likely casting it to a `char`, which means that you're likely to get whatever ASCII character corresponds to the lowest 7 or 8 bits of the pointer.

None of these patterns is very useful in practice, except as a way to demonstrate the lack of type-safety in `printf()`'s argument-passing conventions... but for that, they are very useful :)

Answer (score 3):

You are lucky that the first example works at all; it will print until the end of the string, and since your pointer is not to a string it will continue until it finds a zero character or produces an access error.

Same problem with example 2.  I'm not sure why it doesn't work the same as example 1.

Example 3 is simple - the `%c` expects a single character as input, but you're giving a pointer.  It would be an extremely unlikely coincidence if the pointer had the same value as your character.

Answer (score 3):

All three examples are technically incorrect; given a character code in an `int` variable `i`, the correct way to print it with `printf` is

```
printf("%c\n", i); // pass the _value_, not the address of i
```

(You might be confused because when you use `scanf` you *do* need to pass the address of `i`. That's because `scanf` writes to the variable. "Out parameters" in C always need to be pointers.)

The first example is also incorrect because it's dangerous to use anything but a string literal as the first argument to `printf`.  (There are times when you *have to* pass a string that varies at runtime, but don't worry about that until you trip over a situation that requires it.)

Anyway, let's peel back the "undefined behavior" veil and look at what's actually happening.  This modification of your second example

```
unsigned int i = 'a';  // == 97, assuming ASCII
printf("%s\n", (char *)&i);
```

*does not* have undefined behavior (merely "implementation defined" behavior) and should, on almost all modern computers, compile to exactly the same code as your second example.  On a majority of modern computers it will print "a" and on the remainder it will print a blank line.  Here's why: `int` is almost certainly either two or four bytes. When you store `'a'` in an `int`, the numeric value of the character constant (let's go ahead and assume ASCII, so 97 == 0x61) will be zero-extended to the width of `int`, either 0x0061 or 0x00000061.  When you take the address of the variable you force it into memory, where it will be stored as a sequence of bytes.  But in what order? A majority of computers nowadays are "little endian", meaning that the lowest-value bits of the number are stored at the lowest address, so we have either the byte sequence 0x61 0x00 or 0x61 0x00 0x00 0x00. And that is identical to the byte sequence you'd have in memory for the C string `"a"`, possibly followed by some junk, which is what you told printf it was to print.

The alternative to little-endian is big-endian, in which the lowest-value bits are stored at the *highest* address; in that case you'd have [0x00 0x00] 0x00 0x61 and `printf` would see that leading 0x00 and interpret it as having been passed an *empty* string and so it would only print a blank line.

More or less the same thing may have happened with your first example, since either `"a"` or `""` is a format string with no substitutions if used as the first argument to `printf`, and extra arguments to `printf` are ignored.

The *third* example, on the other hand, hands `printf` a pointer value (we have no way of knowing what the actual number is) and tells it to interpret that as a *character constant*.  Depending on how the "calling convention" works on your computer, `printf` might not even look for the number where the caller put it!  All we can say about this is, it's very likely *not* to print `a`, because the `%c` format code is never going to dereference the pointer.