# Actual address when access violation reading location 0xFFFF.. on x64 visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, buffer-overflow

I am learing about software security and I am trying to reproduce buffer overflow with this type of code:

```
static int ValidateUserCredentials(const char* UserName, const char* password) {
    char validationBuffer[256] = { 0 };
    bool valid = false;

    strcat(validationBuffer, UserName);
    strcat(validationBuffer, Password);

    valid = validate(validationBuffer);

    return valid?STATUS_CRED_OK:STATUS_CRED_FAILED;
}
```

When given the right data in password and username, buffer overflow should appear and it should open the windows calculator.

I am using visual studio 2022

It works on x86 but not on x64. On both I get an error, but on x86 I get access violation error reading location 0x019A4B2 (an actual address) and on x64 I always get 0xFFFFF.. How can I get the same behaviour on x64?

I modified the /RTC1 in /RTCu and put /GS-.

Comment: Maybe undefined behavior? [Why is the phrase: "undefined behavior means the compiler can do anything it wants" true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032551/why-is-the-phrase-undefined-behavior-means-the-compiler-can-do-anything-it-wan). *"Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash."*

Comment: Why is "0xFFFF...." not a valid address in your eyes?

Comment: It should access the location where the windows calculator is. Why would I get an actual location on x86 and always FFFF.. on x64 (the location on x86 is changes from run to run)

Comment: As already mentioned, it's UB. Maybe on x64 the `valid` variable is in a CPU register and on x86 it's on the stack, who knows. If you want to know wht's going on under the hood, you need to check the generated assembly code.

Comment: Also please [edit] and show a complete [mcve] so we can reproduce the result on x86. You mention the Windows calculator, but I have no clue how your piece of code is related to the windows calculator-

Comment: This question is fundamentally unanswerable without seeing the payload you are sending to smash the stack. I hope you have already realized that the stack layout between 32-bit and 64-bit is a bit different? If not, break into a debugger and check the location (and size!) of the return address on the stack vs ESP/RSP for both architectures.