# Why does a global STL container return valid iterators after destruction?

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm trying to debug an old game and I'm running into a sneaky issue with memory management. Here's a snippet of what's happening:

```cpp
#include <vector>

extern std::vector<int> v;

int tmp;

struct Main {
    ~Main() {
        for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
                it != v.end();
                ++it) {
            tmp = *it;
        }
        v.clear();
    }
};

Main m;
std::vector<int> v;

int main() {
    v.push_back(1);
}
```

When compiled with `-fsanitize=address`, it reports a heap-use-after-free for the vector `v`:

- The memory region is allocated by `main.cpp:22`, which is the definition of `v`.
- It's first freed in `__run_exit_handlers` with none of the frames in the call stack belonging to `main.cpp`.
- The bad memory access `READ of size 4` comes from `main.cpp:12`, which is `tmp = *it`.

This snippet covers every detail necessary to reproduce:

- The helper class `Main` and its only instance `Main m` must be placed *before* the definition of `v`. If I swap `m` and `v`, then there's no longer a heap-use-after-free.

  - In particular, the `for` loop will not cause any trouble if moved into `main()`, emphasizing the necessity of the helper class.
- `v.push_back(1)` is required. If `v` is empty or if `v.clear()` is moved before the `for` loop, then there's no longer a heap-use-after-free.
- The global variable `tmp` is there to avoid the compiler optimizing away `*it`. It's not required with `-O0`.

This is reproducible with at least GCC 11 and Clang 14, so I think the code is to blame.

My questions are:

- Can anyone explain why the `for` loop still executes, if `v` is destructed before `m`? How to avoid this?
- In the actual game source, `v` and `m` belongs to different modules and are compiled separately. How can I ensure `m` is initialized after `v` at link time, in `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: Is there a good UB dupe to point at?

Comment: @sweenish I think this answer is perfect for this case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794

Comment: In the code as shown, `m` is guaranteed to be constructed before AND (since order of destruction of static variables is required to be the reverse of their order of construction) destructed after `v`.   So `m`'s destructor will reference `v` after its destruction - undefined behaviour.  Swapping the definitions will correct that.   If `m` and `v` are defined in separate source files (compilation units) then their order of construction (hence order of destruction) is NOT guaranteed (look up "static initialization order fiasco") so `m`s destructor MAY reference `v` after its destruction.

Comment: [Why is the phrase: "undefined behavior means the compiler can do anything it wants" true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032551/why-is-the-phrase-undefined-behavior-means-the-compiler-can-do-anything-it-wan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why the for loop still executes, if v is destructed
> before m? How to avoid this?

The reason is that the `for` loop is - because you wrote the destructor that way - executed (in `m`s destructor) when `m` is destroyed.

When statics are defined in the same source file, the order of construction is the order of definition.  So `m` is guaranteed to be constructed before `v`.    And the order of destruction is the reverse of order of construction, so `v` is destructed before `m`.  There is no way for `m`s destructor to somehow detect that `v` has already been destroyed, and not run the loop.

Reversing the order of definition (in the same source file) is the only option to ensure `v` is destructed after `m`.

> In the actual game source, v and m belongs to different modules and are compiled separately. How can I ensure m is initialized after v at link time, in CMakeLists.txt?

The short answer is that: you can't unless you rearchitect your program.

Although you are concerned with object destruction, your actual game source is demonstrating the "static initialization order fiasco". When globals/statics are defined in different source files, their order of construction (and therefore destruction, which is the reverse of order of construction) is formally unspecified.

You're asking for something that does not exist - build tools don't generally provide any reliable way to control the order of object destruction.

The most common advice is to eliminate the dependency (i.e. don't write code in the first place that causes the destructor of one global/static object to rely on another object still existing).   This is one of several reasons that developers often advocate avoiding use of static/global variables entirely.

An alternative is to rearchitect to *guarantee* a fixed order of construction and destruction of `m` and `v`, such as to declare `v` as a non-static member of `m`  (or of `struct Main`), and not be declared/defined elsewhere.

```
int tmp;

struct Main {

    std::vector<int> v;

    ~Main() {
        for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
                it != v.end();
                ++it) {
            tmp = *it;
        }
        v.clear();
    }
};

Main m;
```

This works because non-static members are constructed before (and therefore destructed after, in reverse order) an instance of the containing class.  i.e. `m.v` will cease to exist after `m`s destructor completes.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone explain why the `for` loop still executes, if `v` is destructed before `m`?

It is **undefined behavior**!  *Anything* can happen, including *seemingly* correct behavior.

In this case, what likely happened is that the `vector`'s internal memory hadn't been overwritten yet by the time the iterators were returned, and so they were still referring to dynamic memory that had been deallocated, which wold explain why the crash doesn't occur until the `it` iterator is dereferenced.

You simply cannot access an object after it has been destroyed, and in your example `v` is destroyed before `~Main()` is called.  Since `~Main()` uses `v`, then `v` MUST stay alive longer than `m`.